# Jasmine test context of a spy

Tags: jasmine

I have a jasmine spy installed on a method, which is called like

```
if(typeof method === 'function'){
  var context = {a:'b'};
  method.call(context);
}
```

so that when the method is called, the `this` keyword inside it will be context. How do I test the context of the spy with Jasmine?

Answer (score 2):

The calling context is in the `object` property of each calls object.

So given

```
var method = jasmine.createSpy();
var context = {a:'b'};
method.call(context);
```

You can test the calling context of your spied method like this:

```
mostRecentCall = method.calls.mostRecent();
expect(mostRecentCall.object).toEqual(context);
```

Check [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-28) for more examples in the jasmine docs.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Koen's answer but I decided to do it more elegant way using custom matchers. Here is the lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spy-matchers

Using this lib you can do the following:

```js
expect(method).toHaveBeenCalledWithContext(context);
```